# Automatically generate classes in phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

It is easy to generate undefined methods in PHPstorm for classes by pressing Alt+Enter over an undefined method.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCk9S.jpg

But is there a way to generate Classes also?

Lets say I have this code

```
    $x = new Person('String', 'String');
```

But **Person is not defined so far**.

Is there a way to *press Alt+Space on Person* so that PHPstorm automatically creates a Person.php class with the following constructor?

```
<?php

Class Person {
    public function __construct($string, $string) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PhpStorm functionality was added to version 9.x (edited again, thanks @LazyOne)

> With your caret over the missing class name, simply press Alt+Enter to fire the “quick fix” menu, then select Create class to open the Create New Class dialog

Comment: I am sure it was at least since version 7.

Comment: @matiit Sorry, but you are wrong. Accordingly to the actual ticket (in my answer) **it was added only in v9** -- otherwise you would not see all those "when it will be added" comments in 2015...

Comment: Ok, I am pretty sure that this answer was talking about version 10 at the time I was leaving my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix (a.k.a. <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>) does not support creation of missing classes this way yet.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6148 -- subscribe to the ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.